# Localizar aspas com espaços em branco com RegEx

Tags: regex

Preciso localizar erros em que dentro de aspas possuem espaços em branco no início ou no fim delas.

Exemplos de erros:

1. A notícia foi dada pelo " Jornal do Brasil".
2. Paris é considerada a "Cidade Luz ".

Reparem que, no primeiro caso, dentro das aspas, inicia com um espaço em branco, e no segundo caso, termina com um espaço em branco.

Quero retirar esses espaços em branco desnecessários, utilizando expressões regulares para apontar o erro.

Utilizei duas RegEx para isso:

```
" .*?"
".*? "
```

No primeiro, consigo apontar as aspas que começam com o espaço em branco, no segundo, quando termina.

Acontece que, existe um problema nessas expressões.

Exemplo:

1. Gosto das cores "azul" e "preto".

Observe que não existe nenhum erro na frase. As duas palavras "azul" e "preto" não começam e nem terminam com espaços em branco, mas, utilizando a expressão regular acima, ele acha um falso positivo no **" e "**.

Tentei de várias formas, mas meu conhecimento em expressões regulares ainda é muito pobre e não consegui corrigir esse erro.

Qual a ExpReg que devo utilizar nesse caso?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Kyllopardiun No meu entender, o exemplo da pergunta está correto. Mesmo porque nenhum falso positivo ocorreria se o `e` estivesse dentro das aspas.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Não. A frase é assim mesmo. Com o **e** fora das aspas.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Exato.

Answer (score 4):

O melhor que posso te sugerir é um regex que case a string como um todo. Pois o problema aqui é que uma análise **local** pode produzir resultados diferentes de uma análise **global**.

Minha tentativa de solução seria:

```
^[^"]*(?:"(?:[^"\s]|[^"\s][^"]*[^"\s])?"[^"]*)*$
```

[Exemplo no Rubular.](http://rubular.com/r/sfJsBA6Zae) Explicação:

- `^` - início da string
- `[^"]*` - seguida de zero ou mais caracteres que não são aspas (texto fora das aspas)
- `(?:...)*` - seguido de zero ou mais de:

  - `"` - abre aspas
  - `(?:...|...)?` - com ou sem:

    - `[^"\s]` - um único caractere que não é aspas nem espaços; ou:
    - `[^"\s]` - um caractere que não é aspas nem espaços, seguido de
    - `[^"]*` - zero ou mais caracteres que não são aspas, seguido de
    - `[^"\s]` - um caractere que não é aspas nem espaços, seguido de
  - `"` - fecha aspas
  - `[^"]*` - zero ou mais caracteres que não são aspas (texto fora das aspas)
- `$` - fim da string

Explicando em linguagem natural, ela pega um trecho fora das aspas, depois um trecho dentro, um trecho fora, um trecho dentro, e assim por diante. Os trechos dentro de aspas podem ser de três tipos: a) vazias - `""`; b) com um único caractere - `"a"`; c) com um caractere que antes e depois, e qualquer coisa no meio - `"a...b"`.

Cabe notar que tudo o que essa regex fala é se a string é válida ou inválida: ela não consegue te mostrar em que caractere está o erro.

**Atualização:** se o que você quer é uma regex que case strings **com** erro - e te diga onde está o erro - isso foi o melhor que consegui fazer:

```
^[^"]*(?:"(?:[^"\s]|[^"\s][^"]*[^"\s])?"[^"]*)*("(?:\s[^"]*|[^"]*\s)")[^"]*(?:"(?:[^"\s]|[^"\s][^"]*[^"\s])?"[^"]*)*$
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hgkoygy/). Essa "monstruosidade" se resume a:

```
^ regex_original ("(?:\s[^"]*|[^"]*\s)") regex_original $
```

Ou seja: "case algo que está correto, seguido de algo que está incorreto, seguido de algo que está correto". Ela vai detectar **um e somente um** erro desse tipo - se a string tiver dois ou mais erros, ou se tiver uma aspa que abre mas não fecha, etc, a regex não vai conseguir pegar.

Creio que com um pouco mais de esforço se dê pra melhorar isso um pouco, mas estamos chegando no ponto em que regex já não é mais a ferramenta mais indicada para o trabalho...

Comment: Testei aqui e a princípio funciona, mas com esse código ele destaca o que está correto. Quero que ele faça justamente o inverso, aponte o que está errado.  Exemplo: http://www.regexr.com/39d0n Nesse link, tente corrigir o que está errado que você vai entender o que quero dizer...

Comment: @Dinho No seu exemplo faltou o `$` no final, por isso os casamentos parciais. Quanto a apontar a parte com erro, não sei sequer se é possível, mas vou pensar um pouco, se conseguir algo posto aqui. (a razão pelo qual eu penso que *talvez* seja impossível é porque esse problema é muito parecido com o do "balanceamento de parênteses" - algo teoricamente impossível de se fazer somente com regex)

Comment: @Dinho Atualizei a resposta. Não está perfeito, aliás é 99% de certeza que se você procurar você vai achar algum falso positivo ou negativo. Entretanto, estamos chegando no limite do que dá pra fazer "com sanidade" usando regex, de modo que *eu até posso* tentar melhorar mais, mas seria no sentido de "desafio de programação" e não "algo que eu usaria em produção"...

Comment: Uau! hehehe! Testei pelo seu link no jsFiddle e funcionou tudo certo. Só não entendi por que não funcionou no RegExr e outros editores de expressões regulares que testei... Veja esse outro exemplo: http://www.regexr.com/39d16 Ele está indicando que a segunda frase (que não tem erro nenhum) está casando com a primeira que contém o erro. Experimente corrigir o erro da primeira frase, o destaque some. Por que será? Muito obrigado, amigo! Já ajudou demais! :D

Comment: @Dinho Comigo também falhou nesse site. É estranho, pois quando ativo a flag "multiline" acontece isso que você falou (normal, pois ele está considerando o texto inteiro, não só linha por linha), mas quando desativo tudo para de funcionar!!! Não entendo por que...

Answer (score 3):

Aqui fica uma sugestão, que funciona no texto que experimentei:

```
var texto = '" Jornal do Brasil". Paris é considerada a "Cidade Luz " Gosto das cores "azul" e "preto".';

var textoLimpo = texto.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, function (match, r) {
    return '"' + r.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') + '"';
});
console.log(textoLimpo); // "Jornal do Brasil". Paris é considerada a "Cidade Luz" Gosto das cores "azul" e "preto".
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zg7otqv9/1/

No fundo divido o processo em duas partes. Primeiro isolando pedaços começando e acabando em `"` (aspas) e depois limpando um a um com `r.replace(/^ | $/g, '')`.

A primeira parte `/"([^"]*)"/g` apanha tudo o que esteja entre duas aspas, ou seja, usando o `[^"]*` procuro tudo o que não tenha aspas, pois fecho a regex com `"`.

A segunda parte usa o sinalizador de inicio e fim de string (resp: `^` e `$`) e usando o alternador `|` no meio.

Comment: +1 só uma sugestão: use `\s+` em vez de um simples espaço, não só porque pega outros tipos de espaço em branco (como tabulações por exemplo) como também previne o caso em que há mais de um espaço nos limites das aspas. Ex: `Paris é considerada a "Cidade Luz      "`

Comment: @mgibsonbr boa dica. Corrigido. Dava-lhe outro `+1` se pudesse votar duas vezes :)

Comment: @Sergio Gostei da alternativa, mas, não posso utilizar desse jeito. No programa que estou utilizando não existe nenhuma forma de utilizar programação, aceitando apenas RegEx. A ideia é, utilizar o RegEx apenas para apontar os erros sem fazer a correção.

Comment: @Dinho, nesse caso sugiro que use/aceite a resposta do mgibsonbr.

Answer (score 1):

Essa expressão pegará qualquer coisa dentro de aspas (inclusive as aspas).
Ex: **"Isso não se faz"**

```
"(.*?)(\w+)\b"
```